# Mapping a virtual directory to mounted file location in Azure file storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, virtual-directory, azure-storage-files

In azure file storage, I have mounted a drive to Azure File storage location.
This mounted drive has images which need to be referred by all web apps and app services. How do I created a virtual Directory using mounted drive? So that I can use the virtual directory to refer the images.

example : `\\{filestoragename}.blob.core.windows.net\images\` mounted to the Drive Z:

How to create a virtual directory called "images" pointing to Z: in my Web Application. So image will be referred using the `www.domainname.com/images/demo.jpg`.

Web App has "Virtual applications and directories" section. But it throws the error as If I try to refer `Z:` Physical path.

Comment: what errors? this is probably a question more suitable for serverfault

Comment: Error : The physical path for virtual path '/images' is invalid.

Comment: Are you using Linux Web Apps or Windows Containers Web Apps? For now , only Linux Web Apps and Windows Containers Web Apps  could mount AzureBlob and Azurefile.

Comment: I am using asp.net application. So It should be windows container

Comment: I am getting the error "Physical path must be a location within site\"

Answer (score 1):

I see, seems you are using code publish web app (common windows Web Apps) instead of Linux Web Apps or  Windows Containers Web Apps (docker/container publish) . 
If you use Linux Web Apps or Windows Containers Web Apps , you can mount Azure storage related resources here directly : 
[image]

However, if you are using common windows Web Apps, the config menu looks like below :
[image]

common windows web apps can not mount Azure storage related resources directly.
The only way to access Azure storage resources here is using Azure storage REST API.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes I am using common windows web app. If I use the Azure Storage REST API , then I need to use the SAS token for all the images to be displayed. So this exposes the SAS token and storage name being used in HTML to the public. In case if need to display 10 images in the web page, then I need to use this SAS token in 10 places. Is this best way? Is there any other approach? I just want the image path has to be simple.

Comment: If Azure storage is necessary for you to store images, and these images are able to be accessed by public , you can store them in a container which enabled anonymous access:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources , so that your web apps will be able to access your images in a simple way .
If only your web app services could access your images , you can try to enable Azure storage firewall:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#grant-access-from-an-internet-ip-range to make sure only your web apps can acces

Comment: Though we don't have any other option to setup the virtual Directory to Azure Blob Storage, this answer is solving my problem and accepting it.  In case if you find solution for my original questions please let me know . I'll do the same.

Comment: Sure, If there is any update regarding to this feature , I'll let you know . : )

Answer (score 0):

We have got an approach that login to the  Virtual Machine where we hosted the web application , Open the IIS and create a Virtual Directory which is referring the Blob storage location.

[image]

Another approach is ....

We have decided to Configure a [Azure custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name) for accessing blob data in your Azure storage account, like www.media.domainname.com.

[image]

This approach helps us to refer static images placed in one location.

No need create virtual directory for each web site.